# Would std::count_if be faster without an if?

Tags: c++, performance, gcc, stl

Here's the gcc `std::count_if` code

```
template<typename _InputIterator, typename _Predicate>
  typename iterator_traits<_InputIterator>::difference_type
  count_if(_InputIterator __first, _InputIterator __last, _Predicate __pred)
 {
  [snip]
  typename iterator_traits<_InputIterator>::difference_type __n = 0;
  for (; __first != __last; ++__first)
    if (__pred(*__first))
      ++__n;
  return __n;
}
```

My question: would it work better (i.e., faster) to use

```
__n += __pred(*__first); // instead of the if statement
```

This version always does an add, but doesn't do a branch.

Comment: @PeterT I guess `std::accumulate` is more general and `std::count_if` is a specialization of it to boolean return values. But is one version better-performing than the other?

Comment: C++ has no notion of "add" or "branch" in the sense you are referring to. This is up to the compiler.

Comment: Identifiers starting with a double underscore, or with an underscore and an uppercase letter, are reserved. Don't use them in your own code.

Comment: @KeithThompson This is copied straight from the gcc STL code; it isn't my code.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus: Which is part of the implementation, so it's perfectly ok. I should pay closer attention. (Incidentally, is `std::count_if` provided by gcc or by the runtime library?)

Comment: @KeithThompson Someone here will know right away, but I have always assumed that these algorithms are taken from header files for inlining purposes. Mine are living in /usr/include, but the omitted macros show they are gcc's version.

Comment: @KeithThompson: `std::count_if` is a function template in the `<algorithm>` header provided by the implementation.

Comment: @Blastfurnace: Yes, but the implementation consists of at least two parts, the compiler and the runtime library. For C, I've used implementations consisting of the gcc compiler and the GNU libc library, and others consisting of gcc and other libraries. I'm less familiar with how C++ implementations are packaged. On my system, the include files that define `count_if` are "part of the GNU ISO C++ Library". I don't know whether that's provided by the gcc/g++ project, or whether g++ might use a different implementation on a different system. (I don't suppose any of this is terribly relevant.)

Comment: @KeithThompson: libstdc++ is provided by GCC. Though you can also compile to libc++ from the LLVM-people.

Comment: @KeithThompson: I was just concerned when you said "runtime library" that you meant something like the CRT or some object code. But, of course, that would be ridiculous.

Comment: I'd be VERY surprised if the compiled code (with any reasonable optimisatin, such as -O2 or even -O1) doesn't do a good job of optimising away the branch anyway. In other words, there will be no if anyway...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The replacement you gave **is not** equivalent, because there are far fewer restrictions on a predicate than you think:

- Anything which can be used in a conditional context (can be contextually converted to `bool`), is a valid return-type for the predicate (an `explicit` conversion to `bool` is enough).
- That return-type can react funny to being added to the iterators difference-type.

> ### 25 Algorithms library `[algorithms]`
>
> #### 25.1 General `[algorithms.general]`
>
> 8 The `Predicate` parameter is used whenever an algorithm expects a function object (20.9) that, when applied to the result of dereferencing the corresponding iterator, returns a value testable as `true`. In other words, if an algorithm takes `Predicate pred` as its argument and `first` as its iterator argument, it **should work correctly in the construct `pred(*first)` contextually converted to `bool`** <sub>(Clause 4)</sub>. The function object `pred` shall not apply any non-constant function through the dereferenced iterator.

The most likely return giving your replacement indigestion would be a standard integer-type, and a value neither 0 nor 1.

Also, keep in mind that compilers can actually optimize really good nowadays (and especially C++ ones need to, with all that template-stuff layered deep).

Comment: And there is the real answer! I'll leave my answer up because I'm a rep addict (and the comments are interesting), but this should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 10):

So, first, your suggested code is different. So let's look at two equivalent codes:

```
template<typename _InputIterator, typename _Predicate>
typename iterator_traits<_InputIterator>::difference_type
count_if(_InputIterator __first, _InputIterator __last, _Predicate __pred) {
    typename iterator_traits<_InputIterator>::difference_type __n = 0;
    for (; __first != __last; ++__first)
        if (__pred(*__first))
            ++__n;
    return __n;
}
```

And:

```
template<typename _InputIterator, typename _Predicate>
typename iterator_traits<_InputIterator>::difference_type
count_if(_InputIterator __first, _InputIterator __last, _Predicate __pred) {
    typename iterator_traits<_InputIterator>::difference_type __n = 0;
    for (; __first != __last; ++__first)
        __n += (bool) __pred(*__first);
    return __n;
}
```

Then, we can compile this with our compiler and look at the assembly. Under one compiler that I tried (clang on os x), these produced **identical code**.

Perhaps your compiler will also produce identical code, or perhaps it might produce different code.

Comment: Good to see they aren't falling down that easily. +1 for compiling and testing to verify.

Answer (score 6):

Technically it would, but keep in mind that all values great than `0` evaluate to `true`. So the called function might return a value other than `1`, which would skew the result. Also, the compiler has means to optimize the branch away into a conditional move.

To expand, there are certainly ways to optimize the branch away in code, but this reduces readability and maintainability as well as the ability to debug the code by eg. placing breakpoints down, and gaining very little since compilers are pretty damn good at optimzing these things on their own.

Comment: Smaller too. There's other fun there as well.

Comment: @Deduplicator Right, sign bits, good catch! I was thinking of just unsigned values.

Comment: The predicate is *supposed* to return a bool. But with templates, perhaps that isn't really enforced?! I suppose one could add a static cast to bool.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus: No, it isn't enforced, or required. In general, the standard library tries to minimise the requirements it places on user-provided types. In this specific case, it counts iterators for which `pred(*i) != false`, so the only requirement is that it be comparable with `bool`.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus I'm not aware of any compiler that actually enforces boolean values to be `true` or `false` exclusively (due to the added instructions that would require). I suppose they could just add an `AND`, but seriously, compilers are good at optimizing code like this on their own, so no need to obfuscate the code.

Comment: There are fewer restriction on the predicate than you all assume.

Answer (score 4):

The code generated by the compiler does not necessarily *literally* reproduce C++ language constructs in machine code. Just because your C++ code has an `if` statement in it does not mean that machine code will be based on a branching instruction. Modern compilers are not required to and do not literally implement the behavior of the abstract C++ machine in the generated machine code.

For this reason it is impossible to say whether it will be faster or not. C++ code does not have any inherent "speed" associated with it. C++ code is never executed directly. It can't be "faster" or "slower" from the abstract point of view. If you want to analyze the performance of the code by looking at it, you have to look at the machine code generated by your compiler, not at C++ code. But an even better method would be to try both variants and profile them by actually running them on various kinds of typical input data.

It is quite possible that a smart compiler will generate identical code for both of your variants.